# Is there a phonegap or cordova plugin for google/gmail based login?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, google-signin

I do see this one plugin "cordova-plugin-googleplus", but with the google+ shutdown announcement I am not sure if this will continue to work for the longer term. Need Advice. Thanks.